# When running my bash script for setting ssh tunneling, it stops half

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

The following is my bash script setting up ssh tunneling. However, it always stops when it get to the echo part. does anyone know why? My distro is ubuntu 20.

```
apt update && apt install -y wget && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install 
openssh-server -y && 
mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cd $_ &&
echo "ssh-ed25519 
AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAII2AOiMJXSWr/yYuAkSur/QSfdwBbmK3hs4qzlMvOQxT dmml@Dmms-MBP" 
>> authorized_keys
&& service ssh start
```

thanks.

Comment: Note that `$_` is an interactive extension and should not be used in scripts.

Comment: Anyhow -- if you run `bash -x yourscript`, a log will be emitted showing each line as it's run.

Answer (score 0):

My response would be better placed in a comment, but I can't get the formatting right, so I'll post it here.  The problem is likely due to a formatting issue.  Splitting the string that's passed to the echo command over multiple lines is especially problematic.  Try re-formatting as shown below, noting the backslash (\) at the end of each line.  There's likely a better way to accomplish the goal than stringing a large number of commands together.  Also, resist the temptation to use "set -e" here.  See comments for additional details.

```
apt update && \
apt install -y wget && \
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get installopenssh-server -y && \
mkdir -p ~/.ssh && \
cd $_ && \
echo "ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAII2AOiMJXSWr/yYuAkSur/QSfdwBbmK3hs4qzlMvOQxT dmml@Dmms-MBP" >> authorized_keys && \
service ssh start
```

Comment: `set -e` is [not good practice](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises) -- it replaces badly-designed but easily-understood default behaviors with nuanced, surprising, context- and version-dependent behaviors. Explicit error handling, as wordy as it is, is considered best-practice in the bash community (at least, the IRC-centered portions thereof, which is the subset I'm best able to speak to collective decisions for).

Comment: (did you read the link? Part of the problem with `set -e` is that a nonzero exit code _doesn't_ always abort the script; it depends on a wide variety of factors, several of which are different across releases of the shell. So it's not even "do this only if you're sure you always want behavior X", it's "do this if you're certain you know all the obscure corner cases that control whether or not you get behavior X when this flag is enabled, and are keeping them in mind while writing your code").

Comment: Thanks, @CharlesDuffy I always value your feedback and will adjust my answer accordingly. It seems the takeaway is this: "set -e is unpredictable; don't use it."  Ironically, I recently discouraged another user from using "set -e" for similar reasons and cited a website that you introduced me to several years ago :).  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328628/running-parallel-tasks-on-azure-using-bash/71330530#71330530.